# How to view list of devices that is connected to my router and select one of them then send and receive data from it

Tags: android, list, wifi, device

I am new to android application development and I want to build an application that uses wifi to connect to another devices (not mobile devices) and sends some data from my phone to a device and receives some data from the other device.

What I have in my local network:

1. mobile phone support wifi with android os.
2. device support wifi connection (e.g. temperature sensor).

What I need:

1. The phone needs to connect to the router and receive a list of available devices and check if the sensor is connected to the network or not.
2. Connect to the sensor and send a message from the phone that tells the sensor to measure the temperature.
3. The sensor sends back a message that contains the temperature.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is nor quite clear to me. But as per my understanding you want to list down some Wi-Fi enabled devices on your mobile & then connect to one of them & finally communicate with them.

For Listing all access points you have to implement the code below.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            List<ScanResult> scanResults =  mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            mScannedNetworksAdapter.clear();
            listView_Access_point.clearChoices();

            if (scanResults != null) {
                for (ScanResult result : scanResults) {
                    mScannedNetworksAdapter.add(result)                     
                }
            }

            listView_Access_point.setAdapter(mScannedNetworksAdapter);
    }
   }
};
```

Now After listing all the Wi-Fi access points you have to click one of them to get connected. To do this you have implement OnItemClickListener & then override onItemclick(). See the code below.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    ScanResult result = (ScanResult) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + result.SSID + "\"";

    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    if(list!=null){
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + result.SSID + "\"")) {
                 wifiManager.disconnect();
                 wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                 wifiManager.reconnect();               
                 break;
            }           
         }

    }
}
```

Then you have to implement a BroadcastReceiver which tells if the access point is connected successfully.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiConnectionEstablished = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            NetworkInfo nwInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED.equals(nwInfo.getState()) && nwInfo.isConnected()) {
               //The connection is established. Now do your stuff here
            }

         }
    }
};
```

Finally there are several methods for communication. One of them is socket communication. You will get several examples in google for socket communication in android.